# Serializing raw objects in windows phone isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have read tutorials how to save data into the isolated storage, but they show how to put text there or XML data. I just would like to save the raw object in the storage(exacly `List<Tuning> list`) and then read it. `Tuning` is just a class.

How to do it? I am using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to persist an *object* in isolated storage.  How would your program know how to put / get data in an organized way?.

You need to serialize your objects into a format that you can write to and read from storage.

You said you have read tutorials, but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156254/Simple-Data-Serialization-on-WP7) is another one that may help serializing your class.

Comment: I don't know about Java, but in the world of C# and WP7 serializing objects is used to convert to and from a known format.  You need to  define the way that data gets converted back and forth.  The [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) does most of the work for you, you just decorate your class with the appropriate attributes.